# React. Conditional Button text not working

Tags: reactjs

I have this Button react-bootstrap component

```
<Button
  className="btn-omega has-icon"
  onClick={() => { handleFavsClick(data.products)}}
  variant=""
>
  <Icon size="1.75rem" />
  &nbsp;&nbsp;
  { liked ? 'Remove from Bookmarks' : 'Add to Bookmarks' }
</Button>
```

The problem is that text inside conditional if sometimes works and sometimes not

The error message is:

```
Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node'
```

The Icon works fine all the time

```
const Icon = liked ? BsBookmarkDash : BsFillBookmarkCheckFill
```

The variable liked is defined here

```
const key = `like-${id}`
  const [liked, setLiked] = useLocalStorage(key, false)
```

basically is true or false

Comment: add some more code to your question, specifically the part where the variable liked is defined

Comment: code added there

the problem is here: "Failed to execute 'insertBefore' ..."

Comment: This usually happens when another part of your program messes up the DOM and makes it impossible for React to correctly update it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52546409/react-notfounderror-failed-to-execute-insertbefore-on-node-the-node-before

Comment: refer to this post it should help with your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23401641/uncaught-notfounderror-failed-to-execute-insertbefore-on-node-the-node-bef

Answer (score 0):

Is working this way (with a span html tag):

```
<Button
  className="btn-omega has-icon"
  onClick={() => { handleFavsClick(data.products)}}
  variant=""
>
  <Icon size="1.75rem" />
  <span>
  { liked ? 'Remove from Bookmarks' : 'Add to Bookmarks' }
  </span>
</Button>
```